# SSRS Report Builder 3.0 using behind a proxy server

Tags: reporting-services, report, builder

Has anybody successfully used Report Builder 3.0 on a company network (that uses a proxy server) to access and build reports on a server that is not part of that network?

We have forms authentication, and all works wonderfully in Report Builder 3.0 when the computer is ‘on the internet’ (NATted, say at home), but the works proxy just won’t allow a connection… any clues as to what needs forwarding / configuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked, if u got any problem with the default proxy, try the ip address

Comment: <system.net> <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true"> <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://myproxy:port"/> </defaultProxy> </system.net>

Comment: Note: you have to set this in MSReportBuilder.exe.config, usually found inc:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Report Builder 3.0\

Comment: The above needs to be inserted into MSReportBuilder.exe.config in the <configSections> group. I added mine just before <userSettings>, and when formatted correctly in XML, it connected to the proxy fine. I used the proxy address as http://[ipv4 address]:[port]